# How to do a sum of integers in a list - Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python, if `list = [3, 5, 6]`, my output should be `14` because `3 + 5 + 6 = 14`!

How is it possible to do it (without using `sum()`)

**EDIT**:

How can I do the same thing but for strings?

Comment: you can write `result = 3 + 5 + 6`. The result should be about 14.

Comment: But I am asking how do do it. Like a loop?

Comment: `L = [1,2,3]; s = 0; for i in L: s += i`

Comment: yes. consider using a loop

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman already helped me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `for` loop.

```
list = [3, 5, 6]
sum = 0
for i in list:
    sum += i
print sum
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is what is known across languages as a [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function.

Your one line sum function:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [3, 5, 6])
```

Comment: it would've worked, but when I program, I prefer not to use the "special" functions like `reduce`, `lambda`, and `sum()`, (that is how I am learning!)